# Імовірний чи Ймовірний на початку речення

Tags: чергування

Правильно вживати **І** чи **Й** якщо *мовірний чи *мовірнісний зустрічаються на початку речення чи після коми?

Вікіпедія вживає обидва варіанти, хоча, здається, здебільшого перевага надається **Й**:

- [Імовірність безвідмовної роботи](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8)
- [Імовірність](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)
- [Імовірний інтервал](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB)

або

- [Ймовірнісний простір](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%99%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D1%80)
- [Ймовірнісна нейронна мережа](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%99%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0)
- [Ймовірнісна класифікація](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%99%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F)

Comment: Ці правила евфонії [такі заплутані](http://p-for.com/book_293_glava_30_§_25._Pravila_milozvuchnostі.html), що їх мало хто цілком збагнути може. Я пас. В багатьох випадках вони просто ніким не виконуються. Початок речення це ж теж неоднозначна річ, бо одна справа, як цим реченням починається текст, а може ж бути, що це речення в середині тексту, та слово, яким кінчається попереднє речення може закінчуватися ж різними звуками, які, звичайно, впливатимуть на ваш вибір з І або ж Й. От я щось, здається, слова «**у**читель» і не чув ніколи, а воно ж-то повинно колись **у**живатися. ;)

Comment: На початку висловлювання я надаю перевагу І та У, Оті слова, що стоять на початку й починаються на «Йм», вони аж свистять.

Comment: Чому ж? Я таке чув, хоча, звісно, частіше було саме `учителька`. А ось щодо `уживатись`, то тут дещо інший сенс надходить, типу не `використовуватись`, а `звикатись`. Хоча, як в першому значенні теж використовується, але, згоден, доволі рідко. Тут інколи є перевага смаку мовця, як саме бажається починати речення, але це лише моє припущення. Наприклад вам не подобається початок з `йм`, а мені нормально.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ну що ж, [правопис 2015 року](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par12) про чергування **і-й** каже ось таке:

> **І** вживається, щоб уникнути збігу приголосних, важких
> для вимови:
>
> а) після приголосного або паузи, що на письмі позначається
> крапкою, комою, крапкою з комою, двокрапкою, крапками, перед словами з
> початковим приголосним звуком:
>
> б) **на початку речення**.

Взагалі це правило вигадали для сполучників, але чудова примітка переконує нас, що

> так само чергується початковий ненаголошений **і** з **й** у словах: імення —
> ймення, **імовірний — ймовірний**, іти — йти, ітися — йтися (ідеться —
> йдеться).

**АЄОА**: це правило страшенно люблять ігнорувати, але то вже таке.