# Вкорінення чи укорінення?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами

Як правильно вкорінений чи укорінений? 
В тлумачному словнику зазначено "вкорінений", а в орфографічному "укорінений".

Якщо мова йдеться про рослини як правильно писати? "Переваги *вкоріненого (укоріненого)* в контейнері саджанця троянди є в тому, що при висаджуванні коренева система не травмується."

Comment: Схоже запитання: [Імовірний чи Ймовірний на початку речення](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1113)

Comment: В яких словниках Ви дивилися?

Comment: Орфографічний словник української мови

Comment: @MariiaMatskevych, який саме: автор/видання (якщо він паперовий), адреса сайту (якщо він електнонний)?

Comment: Словник української мови: в 11 тт. за ред. І. К. Білодіда. — К.: Наукова думка, 1970—1980.   В даному виданні лише слово "вкорінений".  Орфографічний словник учня : А.А. Бурячок - Тернопіль,2007 . Варіант - "укорінений".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Українська мова зазвичай дозволяє на початку багатьох слів і *в-*, і *у-* (наприклад, *вчитель*/*учитель*). Це — один із таких випадків. Сучасні словники дають обидва варіанти:

- Тлумачний [«Словник української мови» в 20 томах (2010–…)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=15083&page=494):

  > **ВКОРІ́НЕНИЙ** (**УКОРІ́НЕНИЙ**), а, е. Дієпр[икметник] пас[ивний] до **вкорени́ти** і **вкорі́нити**. <…Далі йдуть приклади на обидва варіанти…>
- Орфографічний словник під назвою [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) теж містить обидва варіанти (з їхньою словозміною).